# How to get integer value through json parsing

Tags: objective-c

All of you...It might be a silly question but i am new to iOS..I need our help..
I am doing Json parsing..to get some values..my json response is:-

```
    {
        "_id" = 6001256351188711607;
        "access_level" = private;
        createdOn = "2012-12-17T07:06:42.09000";
        "created_by" = 9514682679942790960941872227340;
        description = "";
        keywords = "";
        location =         (
            "12.000023",
            "77.000012"
        );
        picture = "http://54120127762218290878972982207449539830674.jpg";
        "rel_interests" =         (
        );
        source = "Bank";
        "source_url" = "";
        title = ipl;
    },

 );
        "location_description" = "";
        picture = "http://54252499650705298384658551818639.jpg";
        "rel_interests" =         (
        );
        source = "";
        "source_url" = "";
        title = "Air";
    }
```

I am getting title by using this code:-

```
    [titleArray addObject:[[_arrData objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"title"]];
```

but when i am doing this for location i am getting exception thrown....how i can get location??
please help me to achieve this...

Comment: Your "JSON" response is not actually JSON. Is `title = Watch; location = ( "12.000000", "77.000000" );` the result of NSLogging an NSDictionary?

Comment: This JSON should be `location={"12","77"}`. Check json.org

Comment: Also, what is `_arrData`? And what is the exception? You need to provide the exception stack trace.

Comment: @tom    "location": [12.984805, 77.618312] is my json response...

Comment: Also, the entries in `location` are not ints, but floating point #s.

Comment: @tom     k...so how i get these floating values??

Comment: @tom      please tell me why it is giving exception index 0 beyond bounds for empty array...

Comment: hey please paste full json result...not the part...when you are hitting your api on browser then then paste the result

Comment: @Rajneesh071  k..i am posting that...

Comment: How did you access id in your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to get first object

```
[titleArray addObject:[[[[_arrData objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"location"]objectAtIndex:0]intValue]];
```

for second object

```
[titleArray addObject:[[[[_arrData objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"location"]objectAtIndex:1]intValue]];
```

**Edited**
You have a dictionary in which you have an multiple objects as array..In that array's first object contains a dictionary..In that dictionary only you are having location array. to access it you need to follow below code

```
NSArray *location = [[_arrData objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"location"];
double X = [[location objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
double locY = [[location objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
```

Comment: nt working...how we can add objectatindex at two places..is it possible..i don't know???

Comment: Your location key contains array and it have two objects with in  it. to get first object we can use objectAtIndex 0 and to get second object we can use objectAtIndex 1..main thing is we have to use intValue or floatValue

Comment: You can use below code..NSArray *Location = [[_arrData objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"location"];
double X = [[Location objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
double Y = [[Location objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];

Comment: why it is giving exception index 0 beyond bounds for empty array...but array is not empty.....

Comment: Did u log array count..you jst log the array count b4 you accessing it. thn you will get to know whether the array is empty or not

Comment: please help i know i am asking silly questions but i am new to it...so,help please..

Comment: NSLog(@"Arry Cnt::::%d",[arrname count]);

Comment: i checked it...i have total 22 items..for 6 it shows 0 and for others it shows 2...nw tell me what to do to get the values??please..

Comment: can you post whole JSON value

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21632/discussion-between-thavasidurai-and-user1865424)

Answer (score 0):

```
title = Watch;
location =         (
            "12.000000",
            "77.000000"
        );
```

Suppose this is yourDataDict dictionany.

```
[titleArray addObject:[yourDataDict valueForKey:@"title"];
float loc1 = [[[yourDataDict valueForKey:@"location"] objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
float loc2 = [[[yourDataDict valueForKey:@"location"] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
```

Comment: i dont know but u r giving objectatindex at 0 and 1..but location is at only one position seperated by comma..

Comment: Accarding your data dictionary, [yourDataDict valueForKey:@"location"] gives the array and it has two nsstring type elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *loc = [[_arrData objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"location"];
double locX = [[loc objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
double locY = [[loc objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
```

Comment: i dont know but u r giving objectatindex at 0 and 1..but location is at only one position seperated by comma..

Comment: The `location` field in your JSON response is represented as a list, which becomes an NSArray, with 2 entries, after parsing.

Comment: thnx.. but its giving exception..index 0 beyond bounds for empty array..bt array has values..